# Limitations of USB in regard to power

Tags: usb, power

I have read many articles in regard to USB length limitations, and I understand them (no more than 5 repeaters in the middle, 10 or less feet for 3.0, 16 or less feet for 2.0, etc).
Does the same thing apply for voltage?

I ask because my ultimate goal is to power an iPad in a kiosk that isn't particularly close to a power outlet.  I unfortunately don't know the exact length, but what do you guys recommend to best suit that need?

Addendum: We will have Ethernet capability if you feel that USB over Ethernet is better than a bunch of USB repeaters.

Comment: Be aware that a long cable will reduce the power delivered to the attached device, i.e. the voltage drop due to the cable becomes a factor.  PoE, Power over Ethernet, might be a better choice if the device is at the USB max power level.  *"usb over ethernet"* -- Don't confuse this with USB over UTP (or CAT5/6) cable.

Comment: To give you a design advise, we don't need "the exact length". What is your best known estimate of the distance? What is sustained current of your iPad in active mode? What is the bandwidth requirement for USB link in your application?

Comment: Why would you not just run an extension cord and then use the short USB cord, if this is just about power?  This is what Extension cords are designed for.  0 repeaters required.

Comment: @MusselmanLLC: because the iPad is powered through the lightening/USB port, so the OP needs to invent/use some sort of "accessory charger" to have the power separately from data.

Comment: USB powerstrips exist now.  What is the next problem you are running into?

Comment: I think the USB daisy chain is overthinking the solution.

Comment: I think the normal power adapter box connected to this should do the trick, no?     http://www.showmecables.com/product/usb-20-a-male-to-a-female-active-extension-cable-50-ft.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> my ultimate goal is to power an iPad in a kiosk that isn't particularly close to a power outlet.

If the goal of this is just to provide *power* to the iPad, then instead of trying to lengthen your USB connection, why not lengthen the electrical connection?

You should be able to easily do this with an active/AC [powered USB hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DQFGH80), or an [AC USB charger](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DWGLMEW), (located at/in the kiosk) and a long ELECTRICAL extension cord.

Comment: I think the normal power adapter box connected to this should do the trick, no?     http://www.showmecables.com/product/usb-20-a-male-to-a-female-active-extension-cable-50-ft.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Length of USB links is determined from signal loss considerations over reasonably manufacturable cables. These losses are at very high frequency AC signals, where the losses in cable dielectric and cable uniformity matters the most.

The DC power delivery is defined from voltage drop considerations, which include a different set of limitations, mostly from DC resistance of a cable, and contact resistance across connectors. USB specifications define allowable voltage drops, but not length.

However, cable manufacturers have cost considerations, so it is not economical to make cables that are too thick. As result, the cables are usually made to meet minimal power drop requirements, and one can say that yes, cable power carrying capability (in therms of length) is aligned with the high-speed limitations.

Comment: I think the normal power adapter box connected to this should do the trick, no?     http://www.showmecables.com/product/usb-20-a-male-to-a-female-active-extension-cable-50-ft.aspx

Comment: I would not be so sure. 50ft of cable in one USB leg is quite stretching for data functionality, whether it is "active" or not. The DC drop across 50ft **standard** cable can be a problem too. But why don't you try it? But it will be still challenging to find margins for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for powering a device then I don't think you need to worry.  The length limitation is more about data integrity (loss of signal due to attenuation, cross-talk, etc.).

Comment: *"lThe length limitation is more about ... loss of signal due to attenuation"* -- If signal attenuation is a concern, then so should voltage drop on the power wire.

Comment: That may technically be true, but I think it's a lot less of a consideration.  Sending data though a pair of copper wires involves quickly turning the current on and off, resulting in a series of 1's (current on) and 0's (current off).  Just one mistake (turning a 1 into a 0 or vice-versa), will corrupt the data.  But to simply supply a steady 5 volts is much less of a problem, and minor variations in the voltage are OK because there's no data signal to potentially corrupt.

Comment: Electricity, high voltage, low voltage, AC, DC, so on and so forth.... Yeet, Yeett!! Gotta love that energy that we cannot live without and especially when it comes to electronic devices... I would say don't worry about the limitation explanation or else you'll be constantly facing the scrutinization...

Comment: I think the normal power adapter box connected to this should do the trick, no?     http://www.showmecables.com/product/usb-20-a-male-to-a-female-active-extension-cable-50-ft.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it's just power you're concerned about then you do not have to worry.  The length limits in the USB spec are for data integrity (as are the limits to the number of repeaters).  Cable length does not matter when it comes to simply powering a device.

Also, your USB over Ethernet idea won't work for the same reason.  The whole point of USB to Ethernet converters is to carry *data* over Ethernet cables, not power.  The power wires aren't even connected in those devices, except to power the device doing the conversion.  In such a setup, the device on the other end of the connection would need its own power source (which is exactly the problem you're trying to solve).